# How to send two or more SMS messages in iOS, in synchronized fashion

Tags: ios, iphone, sms, messaging

I am relatively new to iOS development and have a question.
I have the need to send a multi part SMS message. I understand that I can just take the long message and pass that into the 'MFMessageComposeViewController' and it will break everything up for me accordingly. However, that will not work, because every message that I send has a specific delimiter and I need every single one of the messages to begin with that identical delimiter. So, what I have tried to do is use a for loop, and display each controller after the other. However, my 'MfMessageComposeViewController' for the other message parts is not being displayed, it only shows the initial message. The warning that is displayed in the terminal is this

"Attempt to present < MFMessageComposeViewController: 0x126819200> on < ViewController: 0x12660ae80> which is waiting for a delayed presention of < MFMessageComposeViewController: 0x12683b200> to complete"

Any suggestions? I tried using code blocks and synchronizing everything so that each Controller would be displayed in a synchronized fashion, however that did not work. Code is below

```
 NSMutableArray *strings = [SmsBuilder createSMS:160 StringToConvert: AddOrEdit:@"PersonAdd"];
void (^send)(NSString *) = ^(NSString *str){
     MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];
    @synchronized(controller){
        [controller setBody:str];
        [controller setMessageComposeDelegate:self];
        [controller setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"111-111-1111", nil]];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^(void){}];
    }

};


for(int i=0;i<[strings count];i++) send([strings objectAtIndex:i]);
```

Comment: You need to use the `completion` block to send your next message

Comment: your `@synchronized` is useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MFMessageComposeViewController has a delegate protocol which will inform you when it has completed sending.  You need to dismiss the viewcontroller in this method and from that completion block, show the next part.

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller
                 didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self showNextMessagePart];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was very helpful. I got it to work exactly how I wanted :) I was using the delegate protocol, but I didn't think to do that!

Comment: Great, make sure to accept the answer so others know that it worked.